# Amazon EB: Deploy Django Application, why it install mysqlclient2.2.0?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I have been creating and deploying django applications for testing purposes.(platform: Python 3.8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2) When I create an environment, and I do "eb deploy" command. After the deployment it gives an error, and informs to read "eb-engine.log", I go read it and I found out that it keeps trying to install mysqlclient. This is the error log:

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Downloading mysqlclient-2.2.0.tar.gz (89 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 89.5/89.5 KB 21.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'

2023/11/03 14:56:16.688243 [INFO]   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mariadb' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1qzq0x_u/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1qzq0x_u/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1qzq0x_u/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 154, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 48, in get_config_posix
        File "<string>", line 27, in find_package_name
      Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
      Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

2023/11/03 14:56:16.688267 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [InstallDependency]. Stop running the command. Error: fail to install dependencies with requirements.txt file with error Command /bin/sh -c /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mariadb' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1qzq0x_u/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1qzq0x_u/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-1qzq0x_u/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 154, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 48, in get_config_posix
        File "<string>", line 27, in find_package_name
      Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
      Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Already uninstalled mysqlclient with pip, and removed it from my requirements.txt
This is my requirements.txt

```
> aiofiles==23.1.0
> alembic==1.4.1
> ansicolors==1.1.8
> antlr4-python3-runtime==4.8
> appnope==0.1.2
> asgiref==3.5.0
> asttokens==2.0.5
> attrs==21.4.0
> autopage==0.5.1
> autopep8==1.6.0
> awsebcli==3.20.10
> azure-core==1.24.1
> azure-storage-blob==12.12.0
> backcall==0.2.0
> bcrypt==3.2.2
> bleach==5.0.1
> blessed==1.20.0
> boto==2.49.0
> botocore==1.31.69
> bx-py-utils==67
> cement==2.8.2
> certifi==2021.10.8
> cffi==1.15.0
> chardet==5.1.0
> charset-normalizer==2.0.12
> click==8.1.3
> cliff==3.10.1
> cloudpickle==2.1.0
> cmaes==0.8.2
> cmd2==2.4.1
> colorama==0.4.3
> colorlog==6.6.0
> configparser==5.2.0
> cryptography==36.0.2
> cssselect==1.1.0
> cycler==0.11.0
> databricks-cli==0.17.0
> debugpy==1.5.1
> decorator==5.1.1
> decouple==0.0.7
> defusedxml==0.7.1
> distlib==0.3.4
> distro==1.7.0
> Django==4.0.3
> django-allauth==0.49.0
> django-cleanup==6.0.0
> django-cors-headers==3.11.0
> django-countries==7.3.2
> django-crispy-forms==1.13.0
> django-embed-video==1.4.4
> django-environ==0.9.0
> django-extensions==3.1.5
> django-fastdev==1.7.2
> django-forms-dynamic==1.0.0
> django-groups-manager==1.2.0
> django-guardian==2.4.0
> django-gulp==4.1.0
> django-js-asset==2.0.0
> django-jsignature==0.11
> django-mptt==0.13.4
> django-rest-auth==0.9.5
> django-rest-resetpassword==0.1.2
> django-storages==1.14.2
> django-tools==0.51.0
> django-tz-detect==0.4.0
> djangorestframework==3.13.1
> docker==5.0.3
> docker-compose==1.29.2
> dockerpty==0.4.1
> docopt==0.6.2
> entrypoints==0.4
> env-tools==2.2.0
> et-xmlfile==1.1.0
> executing==0.8.3
> filelock==3.7.1
> Flask==2.1.2
> flatten-json==0.1.13
> fpdf2==2.5.0
> gitdb==4.0.9
> GitPython==3.1.27
> greenlet==1.1.2
> gunicorn==20.1.0
> hashids==1.3.1
> hydra-core==1.1.2
> icdiff==2.0.5
> idna==3.3
> imbalanced-learn==0.9.0
> imblearn==0.0
> importlib-metadata==4.11.4
> install==1.3.5
> ipykernel==6.9.1
> ipython==8.1.1
> isodate==0.6.1
> itsdangerous==2.1.2
> jedi==0.18.1
> Jinja2==3.1.2
> jmespath==1.0.1
> joblib==1.1.0
> jsonfield==3.1.0
> jsonschema==3.2.0
> jupyter-client==7.1.2
> jupyter-core==4.9.2
> kiwisolver==1.4.3
> lml==0.1.0
> lxml==4.9.0
> Mako==1.2.0
> MarkupSafe==2.1.1
> matplotlib==3.4.3
> matplotlib-inline==0.1.3
> mlflow==1.13.1
> msrest==0.7.1
> mysql==0.0.3
> mysql-connector-python==8.0.28
> nest-asyncio==1.5.4
> numpy==1.23.0
> oauthlib==3.2.0
> omegaconf==2.1.1
> openpyxl==3.0.9
> optuna==2.10.0
> packaging==21.3
> pandas==1.4.3
> paramiko==2.11.0
> parso==0.8.3
> pathspec==0.10.1
> pbr==5.9.0
> pexpect==4.8.0
> pickleshare==0.7.5
> Pillow==9.0.1
> pipreqs==0.4.11
> platformdirs==2.5.2
> plotly==5.9.0
> pprintpp==0.4.0
> prettytable==3.3.0
> prometheus-client==0.14.1
> prometheus-flask-exporter==0.20.2
> prompt-toolkit==3.0.28
> protobuf==3.19.4
> psutil==5.9.1
> ptyprocess==0.7.0
> pure-eval==0.2.2
> pycodestyle==2.8.0
> pycparser==2.21
> pyexcel==0.7.0
> pyexcel-cli==0.0.3
> pyexcel-io==0.6.6
> pyexcel-xlsx==0.6.0
> Pygments==2.11.2
> PyJWT==1.7.1
> PyMySQL==1.0.2
> PyNaCl==1.5.0
> pyparsing==3.0.9
> PyPDF2==1.26.0
> pyperclip==1.8.2
> pyquery==1.4.3
> pyrsistent==0.18.1
> python-dateutil==2.8.2
> python-dotenv==0.20.0
> python-editor==1.0.4
> python-slugify==6.1.2
> python3-openid==3.2.0
> pytz==2021.3
> pyxlsb==1.0.10
> PyYAML==5.4.1
> pyzmq==22.3.0
> querystring-parser==1.2.4
> reportlab==3.6.7
> requests==2.31.0
> requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
> scikit-learn==1.0.2
> scipy==1.8.1
> semantic-version==2.8.5
> sentry-sdk==1.24.0
> six==1.16.0
> smmap==5.0.0
> SQLAlchemy==1.4.37
> sqlparse==0.4.2
> stack-data==0.2.0
> stevedore==3.5.0
> tabulate==0.8.9
> tenacity==8.2.3
> termcolor==1.1.0
> text-unidecode==1.3
> texttable==1.6.4
> threadpoolctl==3.1.0
> tini==3.0.1
> toml==0.10.2
> tornado==6.1
> tqdm==4.64.0
> traitlets==5.1.1
> typing_extensions==4.2.0
> urllib3==1.26.9
> uWSGI==2.0.20
> virtualenv==20.14.1
> wcwidth==0.1.9
> webencodings==0.5.1
> websocket-client==0.59.0
> Werkzeug==2.1.2
> wheezy.core==3.0.1
> xgboost==1.6.1
> xlrd==2.0.1
> yarg==0.1.9
> zipp==3.8.0
>
```

I want to use mysql as my db engine. So, I tried to do it with yum packages. In my django.config file inside .ebextensions folder, I wrote the following configurations:

```
# .ebextensions/01_django.config

option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "myophio.settings.dev"
    PYTHONPATH: "/var/app/current:$PYTHONPATH"
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: "myophio.wsgi:application"

packages:
    yum:
      MySQL-python: []
      mariadb-devel: []

container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py migrate"
    command: "python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
    leader_only: true
```

Answer (score 0):

you must erase the `'mysql==0.0.3'`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.